# What's the difference between Thread Delegate and Define a action by lambda expression in Thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, lambda

I know two ways to create thread in C# .Net, you can use `ThreadStart` delegate while defining lambda expression can also do the job.

Let's say I have a class defined as:

```
class myWorkerClass{

    public myWorkerClass(string configInfo) {

    }

    public void DoWork(ConcurrentQueue<string> executionBuffer) {

    }

    public void DoWork2() {

    }

}
```

And I will construct `myWorkerClass` in `main` function and construct thread for each `myWorkerClass` object to run the `DoWork` method:

```
class Program {

     static void Main(string args[]) {
         int nodeCount = 0;
         using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("config.xml"))
         {
             while (reader.Read())
             {
                 if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                     reader.Name == "worker")
                 {
                     nodeCount++;
                 }
             }
         }

         myWorkerClass[] obj = new myWorkerClass[nodeCount];
         XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
         doc.Load("config.xml");

         int call = 0;

         foreach (XmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
         {
             // Code to parse xml and get configInfo

             obj[call] = new myWorkerClass(configInfo);

             call++;
         }

         ConcurrentQueue<string> bufferExecutions = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

         for (int i = 0; i < call; ++i)
         {
             //Thread workThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj[i].DoWork2));
             Thread workThread = new Thread(() => obj[i].DoWork(bufferExecutions));
             workThread.IsBackground = true;
             workThread.Start();
         }

    }

}
```

My problem is that the lambda expression way of creating threads gives me the error of `Index was outside the bounds of the array.`, but when I used the `ThreadStart` delegate to create new thread, my code works fine. I want to know the what's the different between these two mechanism that cause my problem?

Comment: Lambda capture variables not values.

Comment: @PetSerAI, thanks a lot! Great comment. Explained everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generaly, there is no difference between starting new `Thread` with `ThreadStart` delegate or with lambda expression. Compiler implicitly converts lambda expression to delegate and pass it to `Thread` constructor in the same way as `ThreadStart` delegate.

Difference is that your lambda expression **captures** variable `i`. And (as pointed out by @PetSerAl) that doesn't capture current value of `i`, but instead it captures variable `i` itself. For explanation of capturing variables see for example [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/).

`ThreadStart` variant of your code will evaluate value of `i` **before** `new Thread()` constructor is called (on the main thread). But with lambda expression variant, `i` will be evaluated on the newly created thread, when lambda expression is executed (thus **after** `new Thread()` constructor is called). So some of your threads will likely use wrong value of `i`, depending on how many cycles of the loop was executed, before thread actually started. Finally, if one of the threads is executed after last cycle of the loop (after the final execution of `++i`), `i` will point past the last element of `obj` array, throwing exception.

This can be easily fixed by introducing new variable (for example `j`) **inside the loop**, and copying value of `i` to it. Because `j` is declared inside the loop, each cycle of the loop will have it's own `j` variable, so their values will not change in each cycle, making lambda expression capturing work as expected.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < call; ++i)
 {
     // Each cycle of the for loop creates new 'j' variable,
     // thus we can safely capture it in lambda expression,
     // because it's value will not be overwritten in the next cycle
     var j = i;

     // use j instead of i
     Thread workThread = new Thread(() => obj[j].DoWork(bufferExecutions));
     workThread.IsBackground = true;
     workThread.Start();
 }
```

Since C# 5.0, you can also convert `for` loop to `foreach`. There was a breaking change, that "fixes" this problem:

```
 // This will work correctly only with C# 5.0 or newer
 foreach(var current_obj in obj)
 {
     Thread workThread = new Thread(() => current_obj.DoWork(bufferExecutions));
     workThread.IsBackground = true;
     workThread.Start();
 }
```

Comment: It's interesting that the `foreach` loop has slower performance than adding local variable to get a replica of the index.